# Rotate/Flip staggered dimetric grid tile layout

Tags: c#, math, 2d, algebra, isometric

I have a staggered (zigzag) dimetric tile layout. The tiles are 128x64, so not truly isometric.

[image]

```
float offsetX = 0f;
if(gridX % 2 != 0)
    offsetX = tileSize.x / 2f;

float worldX = gridY * tileSize.x + offsetX;
float worldY = gridX * tileSize.y / 2f;
```

How do I flip/rotate the layout, so that it looks like this:

[image]

I tried swapping out x and y coordinates, but it was always breaking my layout, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Be more clear. It "breaks your layout"? The picture down is a clockwise 90° rotation, and then it's mirrored in the middle y-axis. And you want just a 90° rotation, sothat it looks like (http://i.stack.imgur.com/AOsSb.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(x, y) rotated by 90 degrees clockwise is **(y, -x)**. (y, x) is merely a reflection about the line y = x

Comment: I know my example images are not exactly right, but this did it. So simple. >.<